# Who's driving the boat?

Tags: taken

In the scene in Taken where Brian Mills takes on the kidnappers on the boat, he appears to kill all the swarthy bad guys he encounters. This involves a lot of gun fire which would draw the attention of even the most incurious swarthy bad guy.

So who's driving the boat?

Presumably another swarthy bad guy, in which case wouldn't he grab his gun and join in the doomed attempt to thwart the unthwartable Brian? Or wouldn't Brian nip up to the cabin and pop a cap in his bottom to avoid any potential comeback? Who gets them back to dry land afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These things don't happen often but we now have a definitive answer to this question from Taken screenwriter Luc Besson. He was asked via a listener's email when he was interviewed by Edith Bowman on BBC Radio 5Live on 28 July 2017.

> **Edith Bowman:** This is a great question from Andy Britten who says "You wrote Taken. Who's driving the boat?" Have you heard about this?
>
> **Luc Besson:** No...
>
> **Edith Bowman:** It's the last scene where... I don't want to give spoilers away for people who haven't seen the film but Liam Neeson's character, he does what he needs to do and then... but who's driving the boat?
>
> **Luc Besson:** Ah yeah! [laughs] That's a funny question.
>
> **Edith Bowman:** It's funny isn't it?
>
> **Luc Besson:** Yeah. No, I can't, I don't know the name of the guy who's driving. But you know what? I guess the guy, he has some earphones and he's listening to music and he didn't realise that they were fighting like crazy in the boat. He was just like [makes tinny earphones sounds] because he's on *la Seine* and he's enjoying his [indistinct] so the driver is not even aware of what's going on, that's why.

[Listen on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldQ3TFk6WLA&feature=youtu.be&t=768).

Comment: As  the"  who's driving the boat ?" Question started with Mark Kermode on this show it's a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

I actually thought about that myself.

I always assumed he kills everyone on board, they all have to be criminals. As far as we know, the only reason the boat is there is to pick up a new sex slave. You'd probably only want your criminal buddies around when you're doing that.

And even though it's absolutely not covered / mentioned in any way in the film, I've a sneaky suspicion that Brian Mills can pilot a boat expertly.

Comment: He does have a particular set of skills, after all.

Comment: This is still my favourite answer, but I'm afraid I have to accept the answer from Luc Besson. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know a number of people working in the superyacht crew industry. Basically, they're contract employees, typically hired by a yacht staffing company who puts crews together and sells their services.

Being hired as part of the crew for very rich foreigners is pretty standard, and as a strong rule of thumb, the crew mind their own business (which is safely and efficiently operating the vessel). Sure, some yachts have their own permanent crew, but many don't. Some have a small number of permanent crew, and expand those numbers when needed for voyages. They're all professional sailors; not swarthy bad guys.